# Executing node-jq throws an event.js error

Tags: node.js, spawn

i created a node application which is used to take a log file in json format and after processing the data, we create a csv file. i am using the following packages in the app

```
"dependencies": {
    "bluebird":"^3.7.2",
    "js-yaml":"^4.1.0",
    "json2csv":"^5.0.6",
    "node-jq": "^1.12.0",
    "yargs": "^17.0.1"
}
```

The app has been working properly for last 6 months and there has been no change in code. We did a scheduled deployment 5 days back and since then it does not generate the report and we get this error when we try to generate the file.

events.js:377
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

```
Error: spawn C:\reporting-app\node_modules\node-jq\bin\jq ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)

Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:280:12)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn C:\\reporting-app\\node_modules\\node-jq\\bin\\jq',
path: 'C:\\reporting-app\\node_modules\\node-jq\\bin\\jq',
spawnargs: [
'--slurp',
'[ .[] .logs[] ] | map(select(.context.recordID != "12345")) | unique_by(.context.ID) | map(select(.context.ID != null)) | map({ ID: .context.ID, timestamp: .timestamp, kiosk: .context.recordID, appTransactionId: .context.appTransactionId })'
]}
```

I think the error comes when we try to use node-jq.run method (see below)

```
execute(source) {
    return jq.run(this.query, source, {
        input: 'string',
        slurp: true,
    });
}
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: If you get really stuck, it might be easiest to take the string you are passing in, and use `JSON.parse` to turn it into js objects, and then convert your query into just javascript that filters and selects.  One problem with my suggestion is that it would happen synchronously, so if you are running a web server, and that it a big operation, it might might lock things up

Comment: Ya you are right, i feel like that would be the only way out now.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what the problem was but I tried downgrading the version of node.js to an older version (which was used when the app was built and deployed). I deleted node_modules and package-lock.json files. Did an npm install and the the app started working locally. I promoted the package-lock.json files to the server and the server started working too.

I have a subsequent question. For last 5 months there was no change in the code. Not even package or package-lock.json files. However we did an npm install everytime we generated the report using this app. The dev ops say they did not update the node version on the server. Any one knows how this downgrade of node may have solved the problem?